# ActionSheet/Sheet to Modal in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create an `actionSheet` that opens a modal to save to a view. Currently, I can only get one of the buttons in the `actionSheet` to open to the modal. How can I rewrite the `.sheet` code to do this? Thanks.

```
@State var showActionSheet = false
@State var showAddActivityPopup = false
@State var showAddDayPopup = false

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        self.showActionSheet = true
    }) {
        Text("Show Action Sheet")
    }

    .actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionSheet, content: actionSheet)
        .sheet(isPresented: $showAddDayPopup, onDismiss: {
            print(self.showActionSheet)
        }) {
            AddDayPopup(message: "Add Day")
    }


    .sheet(isPresented: $showAddActivityPopup, onDismiss: {
        print(self.showActionSheet)
    }) {
        AddActivityPopup(message: "Add Activity")
    }
    }




private func actionSheet() -> ActionSheet {
    let button1 = ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("Add Day")) {
        self.showActionSheet = false
        self.showAddDayPopup = true
    }

    let button2 = ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("Add Activity")) {
        self.showActionSheet = false
        self.showAddActivityPopup = true
    }

    let actionSheet = ActionSheet(title: Text("What would you like to add?"),
                                  message: nil,
                                  buttons: [button1, button2, .cancel()])
    return actionSheet
}
```

}

Comment: Which button works? Is there a sequence that duplicates this? Also, have you checked that your three flags are being cleared when dismissing each modal?

Comment: The second .sheet works for AddActivityPopup. Cancel works, but addDay does not. If I switch the positions for AddDayActivityPopup/addDay, then AddDay will work.

Comment: I have noticed that multiple sheets et al. don't like to be in the same chain. Fortunately they can be attached to any view, I usually use `Text("").hidden()`.

Comment: Michael Salmon, thank you! That fixed it.

Comment: Guys, you are supposed to put the solution in an answer? and I am not really clear what fixed it here. Show the code? that's what this site is for.